# Set Icon Image JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, icons

I have a `.ico` file I want to use as the title icon for my program. I'm pretty sure I have to use the `setIconImage(image)` method but every way I've tried doing this has ended in failure.

I've tried quite a few different methods but none have worked for me. One I thought would have worked was the following:

```
    Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Icon.ico").getImage());
    setIconImage(image);
```

Only problem with this however is the type mismatch. Both the main class and the icon are in the same package but I can't seem to set it no matter how hard I try.

What would be the correct method for doing this?

Comment: Where exactly in your jar is the icon located?

Comment: @user432 As I stated, in the same package as the main class (the only package) `me.spedwards.program` is the package and both the class and icon are in there.

Comment: I would use `ImageIO.read(...)` to get the Image directly.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is probably to use `ImageIO` to read the Image from the jar.

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/me/spedwards/program/Icon.ico"));
setIconImage(image);
```

Comment: This is much better than Fisher Coder's answer. 1+

Comment: Not working either. It's still coming up with the default Java app icon

Comment: @Spedwards Are you sure the image really is in the jar under me/spedwards/program. This approach worked fine for me when I tested it.

Comment: @user432 http://i.imgur.com/MZeq0EO.png obviously I changed the path accordingly but that is how it's laid out.

Comment: It's obviously finding the image as there are no errors coming up in console when I run but it's just not appearing on the window.

Comment: You'd have to give some context on your code then. Are you setting the Image on the right Frame, are you altering the Frame after calling it?

Comment: @user432 Here is my code. http://pastebin.com/nwZ1MvUK - I set the icon at line 18

Comment: @Spedwards I just pasted your code into my IDE and ran it and it works fine for me: http://imgur.com/5uHKVdX

Comment: Sadly mine doesn't. Is there a reason behind this? http://i.imgur.com/hKVe43y.png

Comment: Hello, got the same problem, then I changed the .ico with a .png and it worked

Answer (score -2):

This works for me

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Icon.ico").getImage());
```

Here are a few options with a demo [3 ways to Set Icon for JFrame](http://java-demos.blogspot.ca/2013/10/3-ways-to-set-icon-image-for-jframe.html)

Comment: Bad recommendation for an image located in a Jar file. Remember that files don't technically exist within a jar file, and you must get the image as a resource, not a File.

Comment: Didn't work, nor did any of the others on the page you linked.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, thank you. I missed "Both the main class and the icon are in the same package..."